# How to modify the sampling bins for Windrose plots in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am drawing a windrose plot using a library called `windrose`.
Everything works perfectly, except for one part. Here is an example:

```
from windrose import WindroseAxes
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np

# Create wind speed and direction variables

ws = np.random.random(500) * 6
wd = np.random.random(500) * 360

ax = WindroseAxes.from_ax()
ax.bar(wd, ws, normed=True, opening=0.8, edgecolor='white')
ax.set_legend()
```

And based on the data that I have in `df` I get this plot:

[image]

However, the desired output on the same data should look like this one:

[image]

**What is the difference?** So, if you look at the first figure, you see that the degree bins do not start from 0 degrees. In fact, if you look at the bar on N, you see that it is halved. However, the second figure starts exactly at 0 degrees, with the first bar starting exactly at N.

Is there any way that I can shift the bins in `windrose` so that they start exactly at 0 degrees?

**EDIT:** I updated the code above to be a simple verifiable sample. Note that the figures do not necessarily demonstrate the plot drawn using the code (because of random number generation), however, it can be used as a way to demonstrate what I am looking for.

Comment: Can you add few data sample from df? How are your angle expressed radian, degree, goniometric degrees?

Comment: I don't think there are currently options to do this with the windrose add in. You'll have to edit the code yourself it seems. Though dividing it up like that seems kind of goofy, is there a particular reason?

Comment: Reading the doc (https://windrose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#windrose.WindroseAxes) it seems it is not possible at the moment

Comment: I wouldn't say it's impossible. But one really needs a [mcve] (working code) to test possible solutions.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I'd rather mean "not designed yet in the current function implementation". But yes, I am still wondering for a [MCVE] to check out if there is a hack with this figure generation.

Comment: I'm editing the question for a minimal example. Thanks.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest yes I believe it is not designed in the code, but it would be great if one could propose a hack that enables this. Thanks.

Comment: Mhh, I've had a look through the source code and the problem is that this binning is assumed in several places. So there is no easy hack possible. One could monkey-patch the `histogram` function, as well as the `_init_plot` function. In total that would account for more code lines than manually plotting the desired plot with matplotlib.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably try another type of polar plot, or rotate the direction in your source data. You can not do what you need because this is not the right tool.

BUT

The problem is that the desired output *is not a regular wind rose*. In a wind rose, North is zero degrees. In your desired output, how would you plot a dominant wind from the North? Same applies to S, W, and East directions.

Wind rose plots are designed to show the direction in a few, defined categories. From [windrose documentation](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/windrose/latest/windrose.pdf) (I added bold format): 'nsector : integer - number of sectors used to compute the windrose table. If not set, **nsectors = 16**, then each sector will be 360/16=22.5°, and the resulting computed table will be **aligned with the cardinals points**'

The reason for this **alignment with the cardinal points** is the original design and purpose of a wind rose: you are interested in knowing where the wind comes from using four 'main' directions (N, E, S, W), four 'secondary' directions (NE, SE, NW, SW) and sometimes the intermediate 'tertiary' directions (NNE, ENE, ESE, SSE, SSW, WSW, WNW, NNW), totaling **16 possible directions**.

It's not that the desired output is intrinsically 'wrong', it just doesn't fit the convention that is used to represent winds, and thus it will be hard to generate it with the tools designed to represent winds in a conventional way.